# Legacy Code Testing with Jenkins on PHP

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, php, git

We are trying to integrate pull request based testing into our legacy code and the problem is there are lot of errors and warnings needs to be fixed.

So, our first step is while merging new branches into the master not increasing the existing warnings.

Is there a plug-in for checking current problems in master and if there are new warnings with new pull request automatically decline and show only those new issues ?

Comment: Voting for reopening for it is related to build-testing processes and tools.

Comment: @JoãoGFarias I 100% agree. There's multiple reasons why this question is perfectly on topic here. Yes, this question is also perfectly legitimate for software engineering, but it's fine here too. And it's targeted at people with testing experience. What more could we want?

Answer (score 2):

You will need some steps to get there:

1. Have you repository system to notify Jenkins about the PR.

   That will depend on your system. [GitHub](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) and [Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/se.bjurr.prnfs.pull-request-notifier-for-stash/server/overview) have system to do it.
2. [Build the PR branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108380/jenkins-how-to-build-a-specific-branch).
3. [Report the job status](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin).

You can mitigate conflicts using a branching model like [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#gitflow-workflow), so developers can merge more frequently and only send PR without conflicts.